# JavaScript string shows as object when using call and this

Tags: javascript

```js
var d = {};
d.a = 'myString';
d.b = function(a) {
    console.log(this);
}

d.b.call(d.a);
```

In the above code, why does 'myString' show as an `object` when it's logged to the console?

Even `typeof` shows it's an `object`. And with each alphabet split.

I was trying to do

```
arr = ['myString','foo','bar']
console.log(arr.includes(this));
```

and that returns false as well. How can I get it as a string when using `this`?

[image]

Comment: Works in JS fiddle for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your script is running in non-strict mode. If you add "use strict", then it works like you expect:

```js
"use strict";

let d = {
    a: 'myString',
    b: function(a) {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

d.b.call(d.a);
```

The reason is that before ES6, `this` *always* was an object. Any primitive would be converted to an object. This is still the behaviour if you are not running in strict mode.

If it is not possible to put your whole script in strict mode, then just apply it to the function:

```js
let d = {
    a: 'myString',
    b: function(a) {
        "use strict";
        console.log(this);
    }
};

d.b.call(d.a);
```

Comment: This solved the problem. However, I can see that placing 'use strict' at the beginning of the page will require me to make a ton of changes.  I hope it's ok to use it at function level then.

Comment: Yes, you can please `"use strict"` as the first line in the body of function `b`, and it will make the function behave according to strict mode rules.